# Interactive graph Python Jupyter /Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, ipython, bar-chart

I found absolutely nothing precise to make interactive graph with python Jupyter... I have just a plt.plot in Spyder that produce bar Chart, I just want when I go on a bar with my mouse that the name of the bar pop up, nothing more. Same for a curve with some dots arround the curve, I want when I click on a dot, it give me the name of the point and its x (which are dates)...

Again I found nothing exact about it, any ideas?

As an example.

```
[in] Myexample
[out]
2018-01-31     4
2018-04-30    21
2018-07-30    12
2018-10-31    14
2019-01-31    21
2019-04-30    183
2019-07-30    12
2019-10-31    11
2020-01-31    9

[in] Myexample.plot(kind='bar')
[out] My bar-chart.
```

Now I am trying to when I go with my cursor to one of this bar, it give me back my date... It looks basic but again can't find something precise about it...

Thank you!!

Comment: you may want to google plot.ly

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried but since my data are protected and for the demo account of plot.ly people can acess it, I cant use it...

Comment: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/ might be an option

Comment: Sure, I am trying to use Matplotlib, it looks like the best one to do what I want, but I cant find any real examples...

Comment: There is a package called ['mpldatacursor'](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mpldatacursor) which you may want to use. For building your own custom tool, you may start with [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/cursor_demo.html). You should also [edit] your question to be more specific such that it can acutally be answered.

Comment: @user6457870, you can use plot.ly completely offline, no need to share anything.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest yu to use [Plotly](https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/) library combined with [cufflinks](https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/cufflinks/), which a wrapper for plotly and `pandas.DataFrame` object

Both of these packages have a online version by default, so make sure to import the offline version for your case.

```
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
init_notebook_mode()

import cufflinks
cufflinks.go_offline()
```

For your example then you just call :

```
 Myexample.iplot(kind='bar')
```

Answer (score 0):

Code below should work create interactive bar or line plots (also discussed in earlier posts) (Jupyter Notebook 5.0.0, Python 3.6.6)

**Import libraries**

```
import datetime
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotly import __version__
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot 
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()
```

**Create sample data**

```
x = ['2018-01-31', '2018-04-30', '2018-07-30', '2018-10-31', '2019-01-31', '2019-04-30',
     '2019-07-30', '2019-10-31', '2020-01-31']
y = [4, 21, 12, 14, 21, 183, 12, 11, 9]
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y': y})
df['x'] = pd.to_datetime(df['x'])
df.head(2)
```

**Create an interactive bar plot**

```
data = [go.Bar(
          x=df.x,
          y=df.y)]

pyo.iplot(data)
```

[image]